# How to render inside another xml.erb in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, erb

I am a new bee in Ruby. :)
Probably this question is easy for a mature developer, but I need help..

Lets say that I have the following xml.erb that I want to generate every time.

```
<books>
 <item value = <% = quantity %>/>
..
</books>
```

In the above example, if I want every time to generate different items, then I would like to do something like that:

```
<books>
 <%= Item.items.each do |item|%>
<%= write_xml_part_for_items(item)%>

<% end %>
..
</books>
```

In the write_xml_part_for_items(item) I would like to render another xml.erb file.

Is this possible through this way? And if yes, can some one tell me step by step how I can do it, and how I can be syntactically correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a partial view. Create a file in your views folder called `_book_item_or_whatever.xml.erb` and reference it in your books view:

```
<books>
    <% Item.items.each do |item| %>
        <%= render partial: "book_item_or_whatever", locals: { item: item } %>
    <% end %>
    ...
</book>
```

Notice that the partial file begins with an underscore, but not the reference in the render option.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html